# activate segue after email sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Once the user of my app has sent an email and has seen a UIAlert informing them their email has been sent successfully, id like them to then be taken back to a home screen via a segue. at the moment the user has to push a back button to achieve this.

I get the feeling it should be implemented in the mailComposeController method, but I've never programatically activated a segue.

my code is given below:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Disclaimer", "")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Thank you for Dobbing in a Hoon. You will shortly receive an email from Council. Please be aware that the Police are responsible for actioning your requests.", "")
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            break;
        }

            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            UIAlertView *alert_failed = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Email Failure", "")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Your Email Failed to send - Please try Again", "")
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert_failed show];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    if (buttonIndex != alert.cancelButtonIndex) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hoonToHome" sender:self];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need only to pop to your home screen and if the home screeen is nav controllers root view controller try

```
[self.navigationContoller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or if you have a sugue for that use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:nil];
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the transition after alertview's ok click the set alert delegate to self and implemet delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

in this Method add the above code.
I you want immediate transition then place it before or after `[alert show];`

Comment: does that et implemented before or after the `[alert show]`?

Comment: but you can't place a method within my mailComposeController method?

Comment: `-(void)alertView` statement can't be place in my `-(void) mailComposeController` statement.

Comment: stupid error on my behalf - was using != instead of == when i was competing my UIAlertView button index.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set the delegate of the UIAlertView to self and implement the UIAlertView delegate methods.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Then to call your segue.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifierDefinedInStoryboard" sender:self];
```

Or if you're referring to the standard back action of a navigation controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```